# Moment (torque) problem

Tags: newtonian-mechanics, forces, rotational-dynamics, torque

[image]
Why in this figure the total torque on object is not zero as one force cause the object to move in clockwise direction and the other force cause the object to move in anticlockwise direction ?
How about in this case below?
[image]

Comment: Eh? Which one of those forces do you think will make that rod move anticlockwise?

Comment: Hi Clare. Is the rod free to move or is there a fixed axle about which it rotates?

Comment: I think it is free to move

Comment: Find a stick, grab it with one hand at one end and the other hand at the other end, and apply the forces in the directions indicated.  See if it rotates.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You are applying the same force on the other direction but on the other side of the object. That's why the torques are in the same direction with the other torque. If you use the right hand rule then it will be clear. 
[image]
As you can see both torque are in the same direction.

Answer (score 0):

For simple answer without vector take that steering.  Assume that it is cutted at one point and it is stretched like a rod ( discard the inner connection bar) with the direction of force you apply. Then you can find whether they are parallel or antiparallel and whether they are to be  added or subtracted.